# should call configure(...) before calling other methods

Tags: reactjs, customization, apache-superset

Getting list of error when I am trying to run superset.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4jXv.png)

Just navigation bar is showing up, I tried to change the internal api endpoint from /api/v1 to /analytics/api/v1 as I have change the backend urls of apis